# Calculus - Curve Sketching

Tags: calculus

The graph of $f(x)$ has the following properties:

i) $f(x)$  is increasing when $x < -1$ or $x > 1$;

ii) $f(x)$ is decreasing on the interval $-1 < x < 1$;

iii) $f(x)$ has a local maximum when $x = -1$;

iv) $f(x)$ has a local minimum when $x =  1$;

v) $f(x)$ is concave down when $x < 0$ and concave up when $x > 0$.

The question is describe and sketch a graph of $f'(x)$

I tried to draw it but I can't, it's confusing me too much.

Comment: The first function I can think of that fits this description is $f(x) = x^3-3x$.

Comment: awsome, i think i got it thanks

Comment: another quesion is that why can there be more than one possible graph of f(x)?

Comment: As someone already pointed out, we can shift the graph up or down as well as scale it vertically to get the graph of another function with those properties. There are also several other functions which  aren't simple shifts/scalings of $f(x) = x^3-3x$ which also satisfy those properties. I'll leave it to you to find one.

Comment: @user165800 A reason for that could be that $f(x)$ isn't necessarily continuous [at $-1$ and $1$] , so it could be defined piecewise for $x>1$, $x<-1$. Also, The height of the minimum and maximum are undefined so the graph could be stretched arbitrarily up or down.

Answer (score 1):

The first function I can think of that fits this description is $f(x) = x^3-3x$. So, you can start exploring this problem by looking at this $f'(x) = 3x^2-3$ and seeing what properties it has.

Of course, what the question wants you to know is the relationship between a function $f(x)$ and its derivative and $f'(x)$.

If $f(x)$ is differentiable on an interval $I$, then we know the following:

- If $f(x)$ is increasing on $I$, then $f'(x) \ge 0$ on $I$.
- If $f(x)$ is decreasing on $I$, then $f'(x) \le 0$ on $I$.
- If $f(x)$ is concave up on $I$, then $f'(x)$ is increasing on $I$.
- If $f(x)$ is concave down on $I$, then $f'(x)$ is decreasing on $I$.
- If $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $x = a$, then $f'(a) = 0$ and $f'(x)$ is decreasing on an interval containing $x = a$.
- If $f(x)$ has a local minimum at $x = a$, then $f'(a) = 0$ and $f'(x)$ is increasing on an interval containing $x = a$.

This can all be found somewhere in your calculus textbook.

Comment: In the first two points you said that if f(x) is increasing/decreasing f'(x) >= 0 in I. Shouldn't the second point be f'(x) <= 0

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that typo.